# Switching between different coding styles in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, coding-style

I'm developing two separated C++ projects in Visual Studio (2010 mostly, 2008 sometimes). The problem is the first project uses tabs for code blocks indenting, the second one doesn't (spaces are used).

Is there any way to setup my Visual Studio to switch between different coding styles?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio **Tools** Menu there is a **Import and Export Settings...** item.

You can use this to save and restore Visual Studio settings.

It is a simple XML. I think what you probably want is to only import / export the **TextEditor** settings

```
<ApplicationIdentity version="9.0"/>
<ToolsOptions>
    <ToolsOptionsCategory name="TextEditor" RegisteredName="TextEditor">
        <ToolsOptionsSubCategory name="C/C++" RegisteredName="C/C++" PackageName="Text Management Package">
            <PropertyValue name="TabSize">4</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="AutoListMembers">true</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="IndentStyle">2</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="HideAdvancedMembers">true</PropertyValue>
```